# Finding specific string from textfile in .bin file?

Tags: vb.net, binary, reader

So I'm trying to find if a string from a list in a textbox exists in a .bin file. If it does find it to give the location of it. So far I can find a string which I type myself but i can't figure out how to loop strings from a textfile untill it finds one?

```
      Dim j As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ByteBuffer As Byte() = File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Users\PCX\Desktop\ori.bin")
    Dim StringBytes As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("EDC16")
    For i = 0 To (ByteBuffer.Length - StringBytes.Length)
        If ByteBuffer(i) = StringBytes(0) Then
            j = 1
            While j < StringBytes.Length AndAlso ByteBuffer(i + j) = StringBytes(j)
                j += 1
            End While
            If j = StringBytes.Length Then
                MessageBox.Show("String was found at offset {0}" & CStr(i))
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("nothing found")
            End If
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: What is an example of the "strings from a list in a textbox?"

Comment: For Example: List of string is: "EDC16, EDC17, ME7.5 ..."(From a textfile in the software folder) if a .bin file contains one of those strings, show at what offset is it. (note the .bin file can contain only one of those)